# Why do x and y output different values in singleton pattern in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, singleton

In the following code, why are x and y outputting 0 and 1 respectively? Why is it that when I put this code：`private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();` in position ② from position ①, the output is 1, 1?

```
   private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();
//①
private static int x = 0;

private static   int y;
//②
private Singleton()
{
    System.out.println("Starting add");
    x++;
    y++;
}

public static Singleton getInstance()
{
    return instance;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Starting Singleton");
    Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance();
    //Singleton singleton = new Singleton();
    System.out.println(singleton.x);
    System.out.println(singleton.y);
}
```

Comment: @Elliott Frisch,In idea,it can output the result with some warns.

Comment: _What_ code do you put in position 2?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I was able to reproduce with posted code in eclipse. `0` and `1` is the output. Pretty obvious bug. Position 2 is just `private static   int y;`

Comment: @LouisWasserman,private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The behaviour as described in this question is __correct__; if ecj indeed produces a class file that results in 0/1, but javac makes 1/1 out of this, then javac is at fault, not eclipse. See my answer for the odd combination of JLS rules that result in the correct answer being, weirdly, 0/1 here. So, __no__, not 'pretty obviously bug'. (Anecdotally, in about 15 cases ecj and javac disagreed in my long java career, ecj was correct in 14 of them. I advise to all: If ecj and javac differ, ecj is almost always correct).

Comment: @rzwitserloot "Don't write this kind of code". Is the best answer possible here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't write this kind of code. It's, as you figured out, extremely confusing. It *is*, however, according to spec. Weird as it is. Let's go through the considerable steps to explain this. It's individual nuggets of detail about intricate and usually irrelevant details which combine to explain this behaviour.

### The difference between CTCs and initializers

Imagine this code:

```
public class Foo {
  private static final long MARK = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Obviously, the value of `MARK` cannot be determined at compile time - that is interpreted as 'the timestamp, as it was when that field is initialized', which boils down to 'when this class is loaded'. That means the first time any code anywhere so much as references `Foo`, some code has to be executed. During this execution, context has to exist - such code could in theory refer to `MARK`.

Thus, `MARK` **starts off** at `0`, and this code is compiled as:

```
public class Foo {
  private static final long MARK;

  static {
    // Until MARK is set, MARK is 0.
    MARK = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
}
```

That is legal java code (try it; compile it) - that is a static initializer. Run `javap -c -v Foo` to see this stuff.

This:

```
public class Foo {
  private static final int FOO = 5;
}
```

is *very* different. If you run `javap -c -v Foo` on this you'll notice there is no static initializer at all. Instead, 5 is a so-called CTC: A Compile-Time-Constant. The compiler itself resolves it, and places this value directly into the class file. In the first case, `MARK` poofed into existence containing 0, and then during initialization its value is set. But, `FOO` poofs into existence having value 5 **immediately**.

Due solely down to how CTCs are defined, in your code, `x` and `y` **are not** eligible; specifically `x` *does not* have a constant value, that's because to be eligible, the field has to be `static` **and** `final`. Obviously, neither is `singleton`. Thus, your code is identical to:

```
 private static Singleton instance;
//①
private static int x;

private static   int y;
//②

static {
  instance = new Singleton();
  x = 0;
}

private Singleton()
{
    System.out.println("Starting add");
    x++;
    y++;
}

public static Singleton getInstance()
{
    return instance;
}

// ....
}
```

Now it should be obvious why you get 0/1 and not the expected 1/1. First, the constructor runs, with `x` and `y` both being zero. The constructor sets them to 1/1. Then afterwards, x is set to 0.

### But.. forget all that

The real problem is, this code is silly. You don't make singletons AND static fields, that makes no sense at all. Constructors **should not** function as the initializer of `static` context. Constructors are fundamentally related to instances. This code should thus never be written, it's at odds with itself, and you need to know the JLS front-to-back just to understand what is even happening.

The general approach to singletons is to have all non-static content, *except* the field containing the singleton and its accessor:

```
class Foo {
  private static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();
  private int x = 0;
  private int y;

  private Foo() {
    x++;
    y++;
  }

  public static Foo getInstance() { return INSTANCE; }
}
```

The above works fine.

Alternatively if you have static things that need initialization, write an actual static initializer. If you have this, a singleton generally doesn't make sense - just make everything static, at which point a singleton would be pointless:

```
public class Foo {
  private static int x = 0;
  private static int y = 0;

  static {
    x++;
    y++;
  }
}
```

works fine too (x and y are 1 and 1 in both of these 2 snippets).

Comment: Of course, you can also fix this by removing the redundant `= 0` initializer. Or even go a step further and use `= 1` initializers in the first place, instead of incrementing in a constructor/initializer.